# Computing the determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $F$ be a field and let $C_1, \ldots, C_n \in F$, with $n$ even. Define
>   $$
> A = \begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0   & C_1\\
> 0 & 0 & \cdots & C_2 & 0\\
> & & \vdots & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & C_{n-1} & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
> C_n & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0\\
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

I'm stuck on finding the determinant of $A$. So far the ones I've come across have been 3 by 3 matrices with with the entries being real numbers so they have been fairly simple to compute. I was going to use Sarruse's method but then my teacher said I can't as it only applies to 3 by 3 marries.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use induction...

Comment: $(-1)^{[n/2]}c_1.c_2 \cdots c_n$ for any $n$.

Comment: Why not use row operations (indeed, just switches) to make the matrix diagonal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In each step switch top row with last row then after each step the determinant is multiplied by $-1$. Since the total number of switching rows (in order to get diagonal matrix ) is $\frac{n}{2}$ the final determinant becomes $(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}} C_1C_2...C_n.$

Comment: yes thx, was my Latex code mistake!

Comment: You really do need $[n/2]$. Oh, $n$ is even. Never mind.

Comment: @TedShifrin  $n$ is even here, but in general you are right

Answer (score 3):

Expand by the first column to get $-C_n \det(A_n)$ (i.e. 1st column and nth row removed from $A$). Next again expand by first column to get $-C_nC_{n-1} \det(A_{n,n-1})$ and using same logic you get $(-1)^{n/2} \prod C_k$ since the negative sign in front will be repeated once for each pair of columns.

Comment: How could it be $(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}$? That could be imaginary.

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer OP mentioned $n$ is even

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Whoops, I did more work than I should have.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the numbers $C_1...C_n$ go all the way across that diagonal...

Each term of the determinant will be a product of one number from each column, all terms of the determinant will be $0$ except for the term with the product $C_1*...*C_n$. This term will fluctuate between being positive and negative, and the number of negative signs leading this terms will be equal to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, so the final answer should be
$$(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}\prod^n_{i=1}C_i$$

Comment: how do you get a quadratic number of minus signs if there is a linear number of factors in each term?

Comment: In the book "Linear Algebra" by Georgi Shilov it explains that the number of leading negatives to each term of the determinant is the number of pairs of entries in different columns in that term so that the leftmost term is in a lower row that the rightmost term. In this case, all pairs are like that since the entries $C_1...C_n$ form an uphill diagonal, and the number of pairs of $n$ items is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: That's not true. $\frac{n(n-1}{2}$ evaluated at $n=4$ is $6$, which is even, and so $(-1)^6$ is $1$.  Also, what I meant to say was $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, not $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: Actually, you can simplify since $$(-1)^{n(n-1)/2} = \left((-1)^{n/2}\right)^{n-1} = (-1)^{n/2}$$ since $n$ is even, so $n-1$ is odd so odd power does not change the sign...

Comment: Yeah, but I might as well leave my answer like that since that way it also applies to odd $n$.

Comment: Indeed, for odd $n$ the simpler argument like in @nonlinearthought or my answers yield $(-1)^{(n-1)/2}$...

Comment: Note that $(-1)^{[\frac{n}{2}]}  = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} $  for all n. odd and even.

Comment: That is false. If $n$ is $1$, then the first expression is $i$ and the second is $1$.

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer What?!      how did you compute LHS when $n=1$ ? it is $1$

$$[a]= integer ~part ~of ~a $$

Comment: Fine, a better example is when $n=3$, making the first expression $-i$ and the second $-1$.

Comment: @FranklinP.Dyer $[\frac{3}{2}] = 1$ . Probably you don't know what $[]$ means. which is weird !!

Comment: Oh yeah, whoops. But I still prefer not to use the floor function in an exponent - it just gets hard to read, and I'd rather stick with quadratics.

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing answers gives you any intuition as to why any of this makes sense...

The determinant **is the volume of the unit hypercube after the linear transformation**.
(It's the product of the eigenvalues of the matrix, which may make sense whenever you learn about eigenvalues.)

So ask yourself, *What happens if you flip an axis?*
The answer is that the volume multiplies by -1.

What happens if you scale an axis? What happens if you rotate? etc.

So all you have to do is to do more linear manipulations on the matrix to get it into a form whose determinant you can find easily (e.g. a diagonal matrix), and then account for how those transformations affect the determinant.